# Taking two samples from the data but with different observations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sampling

My data is made of about 9000 observations and 20 features (Edit - Pandas dataframe). I've taken a sample of 200 observations like this and conducted some analysis on it:

```
sample_data = data.sample(n = 200)
```

Now I want to randomely take a sample of 1000 observations from the original data, with non of the observations that showed up in the previous n = 200 sample. How do I do that?

Comment: Which tool or package that you are using? Please clarify more.

Comment: @JayPeerachai Pandas dataframe

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using `pandas.DataFrame`, you can simply do it by dropping the old ones and sampling 1000 new ones from the remaining data:

```
prev_sample_index = sample_data.index
filtered_data = data.drop(prev_sample_index)
new_sample = filtered_data.sample(n = 1000)
```

Comment: with the provision, of course, that the OP has not re-indexed the first sample